# Failed changing Windows service credentials to gsma

Tags: windows, azure, azure-active-directory

I am having an error when trying to reinstall the **AADConnectProvisioningAgentSetup** installer. Please see image below:

[image]

Comment: The error message suggests that you check the logs. So what do you see in the logs?

Answer (score 1):

> Failed changing Windows service credentials to GMSA. Please check the logs for more detailed information...

To resolve this issue,

Check the System event logs for **EventID 7041**.The event details provide instructions on how to create a Log on as a service user directly within the Local Security Policy (secpol.msc) like below:

[image]

***Ref***: [Azure AD Hybrid Sync Agent Installation Issues - The gMSA is set to log on as Service - Active Directory | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/azure-ad-hybrid-sync-gmsa-set-logon-service)

Solution 2: Try to generate the KDS Root Key by using below command:

```
Add-KdsRootKey -EffectiveTime ((get-date).addhours(-10))
```

[image]

If a KDS root key was already created by you, Use the **`Get-KdsRootKey`** cmdlet to verify the root keys already present on a few DCs like below:

[image]

If you are trying to utilize an existing GMSA account, use below comment to test sync agent:

`Test-ADServiceAccount -Identity serviceAccountgMSA$`

As per reference doc by Daniel try to check your FOREST functional level like below:

***In server manager -> Tools -> Active Directory Domains and Trusts -> Raise Forest Functional Level***

[image]

***Reference***:
[Azure Active Directory Provision Agent Install failing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/437567/azure-active-directory-provision-agent-install-fai.html)  by *Serenityadmin*